# How to check if I'm coming from a "direct" routing and not from a "back" routing?

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuejs3, vue-router, browser-history

It's basically a simple task: I'm using Vue3 with the Vue Router, there's my `Home.vue` component which lives in the `/` route, then there's a `ProductDetails.vue` component which lives in the `/product` route.

I want to execute a certain action when the user is navigating to my `/` route. However, I only want this action to happen when the user directly navigates here, meaning via clicking a link or via the browser's URL bar. I don't want the action to execute when he is navigating back from `ProductsDetails.vue` (or routing via "back" from anywhere, for that matter).

How do I achieve this with Vue3 or Vue Router methods? I know I can probably do it with query parameters in my URL but I'd prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use in-component navigation guards (read more about it [here (options api)](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) OR [here (composition api)](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#navigation-guards))

Your code could look something like this

```
...
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
 if(from.path === '/') {
   // do something
 }
},
...
```

Comment: Hmm I know about it but my from.path is always "/", even when I come back from "/products" - is this an error on my side, then?

Comment: So there are two cases:
1. Home -> special page
2. Home -> Product details -> special page
And you only want to execute a specific action in the first case right?
Maybe update your question with your router config